# Why is the Orbifold Euler characteristic of $M_{1, 1}$ equal to $\zeta(-1) $

Tags: riemann-zeta, analytic-continuation, moduli-space, orbifolds

The orbifold euler characteristic of $M_{1, 1}$= $PSL(2, \mathbb{Z}) $/$\mathbb{H}$is equal to -1/12. 
This is due to the fact that $M_{1,1}$ has one two-cell with $\mathbb{Z_{2}}$ automorphism, two one-cells with $\mathbb{Z_{2}}$ automorphism and two points with automorphisms$\mathbb{Z_{4}}$ and$\mathbb{Z_{6}}$.
Is there any alternative perspective to the analytic contiuation of the Riemann Zeta Function that this might indicate?

Comment: Is it given by a special value of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selberg_zeta_function ?

Comment: I think the following paper answers the question:

J. Harer and D. Zagier, The Euler characteristic of the moduli space of curves, Invent. Math.
85 no. 3 (1986), 457-485.